# TWIG Query Builder In Repo

Tags: symfony, doctrine, twig

I have tried to put this into referralentity.php

```
public function getTotalReferrals()
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('r');
    $qb->select('COUNT(r.id) AS totalReferral, r.referrer_id')
        ->where('r.status = :status')
        ->setParameter('status', 'Completed')
        ->groupBy('r.referrer_id')
        ->orderBy('totalReferral', 'DESC');
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

My twig code.

```
{% for referral in totalreferrallist %}
    Referrer ID: {{ referral.referrer_id }}
    Total Referrals: {{ referral.totalReferral }}
{% endfor %}
```

The original code which brings the results up in phpmyadmin is

```
SELECT COUNT(r.`id`) AS totalReferral, r.`referrer_id` FROM `referral` r WHERE r.`status` = 'Completed' GROUP BY r.`referrer_id` ORDER BY `totalReferral` DESC
```

I am very confused as to why this is now not showing the correct results.

If i display the twig as below it will show me the referral ID but thats it, i guess that is being pulled from the referralentity.

```
{% for totalreferrallist in totalreferrallist %}
    Referrer ID: {{ totalreferrallist.id }}
    Total Referrals: {{ totalreferrallist.id }}
{% endfor %}
```