# symfony doctrine SQL QueryBuilder in entity to template

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have a function in my referralentity.php

```
public function getTotalReferrals($user)
{
  $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('r');
    $qb->select('COUNT(r.id) AS totalReferral, r.referrer_id')
        ->where('r.status = :status')
        ->setParameter('status', 'Completed')
        ->groupBy('r.referrer_id')
        ->orderBy('totalReferral', 'DESC');
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();

}
```

in my template file i try to call this it works but it only shows the referral ID.

```
      {% for getTotalReferrals in getTotalReferrals %}
  <tr></tr>
  
  <td> Referrer ID: {{ getTotalReferrals.id }}</td>
<td>  Total Referrals: {{ getTotalReferrals.totalReferral }}</td>
    
{% endfor %}
```

I get the following error

```
Neither the property "totalReferral" nor one of the methods "totalReferral()", "gettotalReferral()"/"istotalReferral()"/"hastotalReferral()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "App\Entity\ReferralEntity".
```

Is this because i also have

```
/**
 * Get id.
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}
```

Within the entity so it pulls the ID from that function and ignores my getTotalReferrals function?

The original query i am trying to pull is

```
LEFT JOIN SELECT COUNT(r.`id`) AS totalReferral, r.`referrer_id` FROM `referral` r WHERE r.`status` = 'Completed' GROUP BY r.`referrer_id` ORDER BY `totalReferral` DESC
```

Comment: How does this question differs from the one [you've asked previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76257466/twig-query-builder-in-repo)?

Comment: There is no proper answer to your question since, using symfony and twig, this is not a practice to call repository function inside twig or whatever near that. My best help would be to give you this link : https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony-doctrine It will help you to understand how symfony is used with doctrine. This is an official tutorial. Do it properly and will be very good on this.

Comment: "*this is not a practice to call repository function inside twig*" - What do you mean with this? There is no difference in creating a `Twig\Function` than passing the records directly from the controller

Comment: How does the (paid) provided link answer the question on OP? As far as I can see, the "tutorial" doesn't explain anything on aggregated fields, nor on how to access these

Comment: Sorry i think i did not ask the correct question before, I have since then made changes and got to this point, regarding the entity i am lost to see where the getTotalReferrals.id is being pulled from

Comment: Only the video need a payment, but bellow the video there is everything explained textually and this is literally the transcript of what is said inside the video. Could be enough.
And yes, in fact you can call doctrine repository function inside twig function. But being able to do something dosnt mean this is a good idea. For what i understand of the author usecase. It is not.

Comment: So lets say you have an X amount of offices and you want to list the offices on every page, how would you pass the offices to every template?

Comment: It's better to update your existing question with the new attempts/information rather than asking a new question

Comment: This https://symfony.com/doc/6.3/http_cache/esi.html 
Or https://symfony.com/doc/6.3/templates.html#embedding-controllers
Twig function biggest usage is to define custom filter. I know there a new method also, but didnt manage to find the documentation.

Comment: Also this https://symfony.com/doc/6.3/templates.html#global-variables

Comment: Once again sorry, i have been trying to code this for a long long time now and just struggling to find the solution. i am assuming its a problem with my logic so will have to keep trying